# Android: How to get custom XML recognized

Tags: android, xml

I'm fairly new to Android Dev, and trying to understand how to incorporate open-source/third party extensions/plug-ins.

I've tried to include two different packages via the add to Gradle method, most recently the library at https://github.com/silvestrpredko/DotProgressBarExample/tree/master/app

which instructs to add the following Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:0.1.4@aar'
```

Currently my Gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.e.crispens.tuna"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:0.1.4@aar'
}
```

And, as per docs I've created a layout with the following XML (relevant parties copied straight from the docs):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.e.crispens.tuna.StringFragment">

    <com.github.silvestrpredko.dotprogressbar.DotProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dot_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        custom:amount="5"
        custom:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        custom:endColor="@color/light_blue_A400"
        custom:startColor="@color/light_blue_A700"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/crispensmith/AndroidStudioProjects/Tuna/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_string.xml
Error:(7) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/crispensmith/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What is the correct way to incorporate these packages using custom XML?

Comment: `custom:amount`, for example, the `custom` is an "unbound prefix"

Comment: Yup, got that.  But according to the Github page for the plugin, that should be resolved by including the dependency in the build.gradle file, shouldn't it?

Comment: For those Github projects, if something doesn't work as documented, best to poke around the app example source code

Comment: Nope, no disrespect intended but I still don't think you're getting the real meat of the question.  Please see the accepted answer.  Cheers, though.

Comment: I'm just saying, since you understood the error, the resources to compare your code with a supposedly working solution shouldn't be too difficult to trace

Comment: But what I didn't understand, and what the accepted answer explains is that my namespace references don't automagically update and need maintenance; so  I was looking at this invalid XML not realizing that it wasn't automatically validated.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Yeah, the XML isn't validated until the processResources step of Gradle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114491/discussion-between-crispen-smith-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the declaration of the `custom` namespace, you can define it by adding onto your FrameLayout this attribute

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define the `custom` namespace in your XML. If you look at the sample code [here](https://github.com/silvestrpredko/DotProgressBarExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml). You can see that in this sample the custom namespace has been declared. You should declare it too, like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.e.crispens.tuna.StringFragment">

    <com.github.silvestrpredko.dotprogressbar.DotProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dot_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        custom:amount="5"
        custom:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        custom:endColor="@color/light_blue_A400"
        custom:startColor="@color/light_blue_A700"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because it explains the issue and the resolution and for providing a thorough code example.  Many thanks.